# How to fix 'GOPATH not set' error when using go build

Tags: go

I am trying to build some go project. Running `go build` from the project directory returns following error:

```
../../../github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/integrations.go:4:2: cannot find package "bufio" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/bufio (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set. For more details see: 'go help gopath')
vendor/github.com/getsentry/raven-go/client.go:5:2: cannot find package "bytes" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/gitlab.com/company/bc_to_influx/vendor/bytes (vendor tree)
    /home/user/go/src/bytes (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set. For more details see: 'go help gopath')
vendor/github.com/getsentry/raven-go/client.go:6:2: cannot find package "compress/zlib" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/gitlab.com/company/bc_to_influx/vendor/compress/zlib (vendor tree)
    /home/user/go/src/compress/zlib (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set. For more details see: 'go help gopath')
../../../github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/client.go:4:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/context (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set. For more details see: 'go help gopath')
vendor/github.com/getsentry/raven-go/client.go:7:2: cannot find package "crypto/rand" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/gitlab.com/company/bc_to_influx/vendor/crypto/rand (vendor tree)
    /home/user/go/src/crypto/rand (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set. For more details see: 'go help gopath')
```

and so on for the various packages required by the project.
There are many issues that arise:

- GOPATH is declared as 'not set', whereas it is actually set to "/home/user/go", as I could see by running `go env` (btw, GOROOT is set to "/home/user/go", which I believe may cause some trouble as I've understood GOPATH and GOROOT should be different)
- go seems to look for packages such as bufio for example in "/home/user/go/src/bufio" whereas I would like it to search in "/home/user/go/src/github.com/bufio"

A workaround is to use `sudo go build`, which works fine, but I'd like to properly fix the issue. For root user, GOPATH is set to "/root/go" and GOROOT is set to "/snap/go/4762".

I am using govendor, and GO111MODULE is set to off.

Answer (score 0):

This is all wrong.

1. `go env` does **not** work like `printenv`: It prints the values *used* which are values deliberately set or the default values. Your GOPATH is unset and `go env`prints the default.
2. Never, literally **NEVER** set GOROOT. Never. GOROOT is for experts doing expert stuff. It is *never* needed to build, compile, test, whatnot normal Go code if you have a properly set up Go installation.
3. Never do `sudo go whatever`. Sudo is not the magical make-it-work!! hammer.
4. The README of govendor says: **Use Go modules**.

Just stop trying to be clever. Install Go according to the official installation instructions, do not mess with GOROOT. Set or don't set GOPATH. If working in GOPATH-mode you **must** `go get` the dependencies yourself before compiling your code. Use Go modules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ```printenv``` does show that my GOPATH is set, but the problem is, as you pointed out, that I should use Go modules. The reason I tried not to use it is I am using depencies that don't exist in github any more, so I need a static vendor.